# How do I control the spacing/scaling of geom_text on the y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I do not know how to control the spacing of the text between "rows" in ggplot2. For example, the function below plots rows of text on an empty grid:

```
library(tidyverse)
plot_text <- function(rows) {
  tibble(text = sprintf("Line %s", 1:rows), 
         x = 1, 
         y = rev(1:rows)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = text)) +
    theme_void() +
    ylim(-5, rows) #I want to leave some whitespace on the bottom
}
```

However, the spacing between each "row" varies according to the number of rows:

```
plot_text(rows = 5)
plot_text(rows = 10)
plot_text(rows = 20)
```

How can I lock or control the spacing between rows, so that the text always scales the same, no matter the number of rows?

Comment: it scales the same as is, if you fix the ylim for instance: `ylim(-5, 20)`

Comment: True, but the text no longer starts at the top of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any attempts that I have made with a variable `ylim` proved to be inconsistent, so I decided to fix the ylim and conform to that:

```
library(tidyverse)
plot_text <- function(rows) {
  if(rows < 1){
    stop ("try again")}
  if(rows == 1){
    g = 20
  } else { g = c(20,20-1*(1:(rows-1)))}
  tibble(text = sprintf("Line %s", 1:rows), 
         x = 1, 
         y = g) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y = y)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = text)) +
    theme_void()+
    ylim(-5, 20) 
}
library(gridExtra)
do.call("grid.arrange", c(lapply(1:10, function(x) plot_text(x)), ncol = 5))
```

[image]